# How to identify if uploaded file(s) has been completely uploaded?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, progress-bar

My goal is to create a html5 meter tag progress bar. I know that javascript is the best way to do this. The meter tag value attribute updates as the upload progresses. But I don't know how to code javascript and I need this quick. I know there are plugins available, but the majority of them are packaged as a set(with the upload button, and other stuff). I just need a progress bar that can read the uploaded files of my users and adjusts the meter tag value by percentage of the uploaded files.

Note: There is a multiple attribute included.

```
<input name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple>
```

So maybe any of you can help?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in tons of ways. One of those is described here: http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-html5-file-upload/ another is here http://www.amitpatil.me/ajax-file-upload-html5-drag-and-drop-file-upload/

Also read through documentation for progress events http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/ - it has both `progress` event, and `load` event, which is fired once the progress is complete.